# How do i access my json array with key named "data" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have json response returned from a rest api as below

```
{
  "data": [{ "id": "86", "name": "Hello", "last_name": "world" }],
  "extra": { "message": "Hello", "additionalmessage": "world" }
};
```

I use jsonparse to convert it into object in javascript as below

> var obj = JSON.parse(e.data)

When i access **obj.extra.message it prints "Hello".**

But when i try to access obj.data[0] , i get [object][Object] ,
seems like its taking "data" as a keyword?

**How can i overcome this?**

Comment: data is an **array**, is working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have your object inside an array.
Javascript doesn't show the whole object; you must use object's keys to access its data.

`Obj.data[0]` is the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your response is already JSON. So don't parse it again:

```
const data = {
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"86",
         "name":"Hello",
         "last_name":"world"
      }
   ],
   "extra":{
      "message":"Hello",
      "additionalmessage":"world"
   }
}

console.log(data["data"][0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parsing is working just fine; it's just that when you output the first element, you're just outputting the object, not one of its properties. The default toString on an object outputs [object Object]

You can try  this:

```
var user = obj['data'][0];         
console.log(user.name);   
console.log(user.last_name);
```

Or try

```
JSON.stingify(obj.data[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how you can do it:

```js
var obj = {
  "data": [{ "id": "86", "name": "Hello", "last_name": "world" }],
  "extra": { "message": "Hello", "additionalmessage": "world" }
};

console.log(obj["data"][0]["id"]);
```